# Какие существуют библиотеки C++ для создание HTTP сервера не клиента

Tags: c++, http

Может у кого есть список библиотек для создания сервера http, крайне желательно  чтобы присутствовала в пакетном менеджере MSYS2. С адекватными примерами и на русском.

Пробовал boost asio , libevent. Пример запускаються но в первом не отдает браузеру верный ответ, второй не предоставляет список аргументов запроса.
ещё несколько пробовал но там программа после компиляции просто вылетает с вызовом исключений.

Единственный пример адекватно заработал и я смог построить на нем свою структуру это чистые сокеты, но они иногда намертво зависают при запросе с пк.

С адекватным пояснением на русском нашёл  uWebSockets но он (библиотека) не собирается у меня а значит бесполезен

Поделитесь списком библиотек и ссылкой на пример или лучше адекватный урок.

MinGW C++ CodeBlocks

Comment: если у Вас есть пример с чистыми сокетами - перемещайте их в отдельный поток и ничего не будет выснуть.

Comment: Я имел ввиду у клиента зависает, делаем с клиента запросс, зависает у всех клиентов, у того что завис обновляем страницу так как она бесконечно грузиться, работает у всех, но иногда проявляеться у другого клиента и это не недежно что один клиент может повесить сервер, думал сделать стото локального кахута, или автоматизированую локальною мафию. Ето не то что нужно, я так и не разобрался почему виснет.

Comment: либо изучайте, как делать неблокирующий ввод-вывод (select/poll/kpoll) или на сервере для каждого клиента делайте отдельный поток (да, это старомодно, но это работает)

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/edison/blog/280932/ - вполгне работоспособный вариант

Comment: Благодарю, Чесно говоря есть некая неприязнь к qt с того момента когда друг посоветовал qt creater и озвучил их политику. Но тут  действительно есть пояснения , если не разберусь с cpp-httplib то  попробую если удастся установить в mingw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [cpp-httplib](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib)

Простой как табуретка, и header-only (поэтому не страшно, что его нет в пакетах MSYS2).

Для чего-то очень серьезного вряд ли подойдет, но если нужно быстро поднять сервер на коленке, то вполне.

Comment: С первого раза пример заработал, и библиотека  единственное нужно было либы включить ws2_32, wsock32 благодарю выглядит класно буду еще пробовать но первые впечатления на высоте особенно пример hello.cc ничего лишнего

Comment: Начал разбираться более серьёзно с библиотекой, и я не вижу ни одного примера чтобы он позволил сделать обработку запросов, эта библиотека позволяет обработать запрос? Если да то как? Если она только статические страницы отдает, то ето не вариант, ни обновления данных о программе, ни управления программой из веб интерфейса.

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка Задайте отдельный вопрос. Вижу в ридми примеры обработки запросов.

Comment: Оформил отдельно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1377188/http-сервер-на-cpp-httplib-запросы-и-динамические-ответы