# HTTP сервер на cpp-httplib запросы и динамические ответы

Tags: c++, http, запрос, get

Ранее задавал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1375025/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8-c-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-http-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0/1375072?noredirect=1#comment2446392_1375072) о том **какую библиотеку использовать** **для создания** веб интерфейса в программе с++, по сути **http сервера на с++**, [HolyBlackCat](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/215103/holyblackcat) по**совет**овал **cpp-httplib.**
Библиотека очень понравилась так как состоит только с одного *.h файла что упрощает установку до невозможности. да и простота.

Вот пример запуска сервера самый простой

```
  //
//  hello.cc
//
//  Copyright (c) 2019 Yuji Hirose. All rights reserved.
//  MIT License
//

#include <httplib.h>
using namespace httplib;

int main(void) {
  Server svr;

  svr.Get("/hi", [](const Request & /*req*/, Response &res) { //Про запросу к адресу 192.168.0.102:8080/hi Вернуть текст как страницу
    res.set_content("Hello World!", "text/plain"); //Текст для возврата и формат
  });
  
    svr.Get("/", [](const Request & /*req*/, Response &res) { //Про запросу к адресу 192.168.0.102:8080/ Вернуть текст как страницу
    res.set_content("Main Pages!", "text/plain"); //Текст для возврата и формат
  });

  //Команда запускает цикл так что в реальных проектах в отдельный процесс её
  svr.listen("192.168.0.102", 8080); // 192.168.0.102:8080 Ип куда розшарить, Ип вашого пк ну и порт какой то главное чтобы не был занят всякими торрентами иле open server
  
  //Проверок не делаем , по этому если программа просто завершала роботу то нужно использовать правильный ип
  //список можно получить командой в консоли ipconfig берем ип lan иле wlan
  }
```

Но как обрабатывать запросы ? , например в сокетах  мы указываем функцию куда их слать, а в самой функции уже парсим url и исходя из запроса формируем страницу и возвращаем пользователю , [всё ясно понятно но так и не решил проблему зависания](https://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-networks/thread2892221.html), по этому  начал искать альтернативу. В httplib я не увидел ничего знакомого ни в одном примере.

**Как в библиотеке [httplib](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib)  получить запрос обработать его и вернуть ответ отправителю с новими данными?**

И под словами обработать, я имею ввиду получить масив get аналог в php $_GET. посмотреть что клиент запросил у севера используя get запрос, буть то значение переменной или файл, мы возвращаем это. Обработчик конечно же я сам напишу, но как его создать и возвращать динамически страницу.
Логичнее было бы если бы svr.Get иле аналог принимала не текст а функцию обработчик. в которую при запросе слала бы какую клиент страницу запросили тип запроса Get Post и масив, ключ значение.

Comment: Так прям в вопросе Вы привели два примера ответа на Ваш вопрос

Comment: Каких? Я не понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду? Я имел в виду запрос get который прилетит мне где то в функцию, я обработаю и в зависимости од запроса например запущу секунд на сервере а тому кто послал запрос верну страницу с текстом сделано остновить?

Comment: Вам нужен для этого поток. запускаете поток, а пользователю отвечаете  `res.set_content("wait please!", "text/plain");`. Все. А вот что бы остановить, нужно пользователю послать ещё какой то айди/номерок. Потом, когда юзер запросит статус с этим номером, нужно найти в своих задачах данные о этом потоке и послать пользователю. Ничего необычного.

Comment: Ка я узнаю если пользователь, отправит запрос 192.168.0.106:8080? =100&usComan=SetVolume    Как узнать какие значения пользователь указал в запросе можна сказать в переменных  usComan и usVal

Comment: Допустим я вызову повторно res.set_content("Newtext 1!", "text/plain"); в следующий раз   res.set_content("Newtext 2!", "text/plain"); Но как среагировать на запрос моему коду как проверить что мне пользователь прислал?

Comment: Вам параметр request для чего? Он для этого и нужен.

Comment: Так что я туда должен положить?

Comment: Можете пример показать как просто в консоль выводить что клиент отправил запрос , и список аргументов.

Comment: И чтобы при посещении страницы на странице писало сколько раз ее открыли

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я посмотрел внутрь кода, вроде там многопоточность не используется, поэтому для счетчика я буду использовать простой `int`. Если что - всегда можно переделать его в атомик или обложить мютексом (хотя тут как всегда нужно быть аккуратным).

Для начала заведем глобальную переменную-счетчик

```
int counter = 0;
```

(да, глобальные переменные это не очень, но для нашего примера сойдет. в общем случае здесь будет какой то синглтон или что лучше). И добавляем такой обработчик

```
svr.Get("/counter", [](const httplib::Request& req, httplib::Response& res) {
  counter++;
  res.set_content("counter = " + std::to_string(counter), "text/plain");
});
```

все, готово. Теперь можно в браузере зайти на http://127.0.0.1:8080/counter и видеть счетчик, который постоянно увеличивается. Ок, первая половина готова.

Перейдем к второй половине

> как просто в консоль выводить что клиент отправил запрос , и список аргументов

выведем пользователю его же параметры get запроса!

```
svr.Get("/show", [](const httplib::Request& req, httplib::Response& res) {
  //std::cout << "aaa, пользователь нам прислал запрос\n";
  std::string s;
  for (auto p : req.params) {
    s+= p.first + ":" + p.second + "\n";
  }
  res.set_content(s, "text/plain");
});
```

тут все просто и очевидно - в цикле пробегаем по параметрам и добавляем их в строку, потом это все распечатываем пользователю. Если теперь написать что то вида http://127.0.0.1:8080/show?data=test&q=1

то пользователь увидит такое

```
data:test
q:1
```

Comment: Благодарю, раньше не сталкивался с такой конструкцией в с++ только в js. думал то что в скобках компилируется в статическую страницу  и больше не выполняться, вы действительно помогли. С этим можно работать. Есть еще доп порос но постараюсь сам разобраться если не розберусь то оформлю

Comment: Так Вам просто нужно чуточку с++ подучить?

Comment: Разве  это не фишка нового стандарта ? Так как когда я учил с++ такого не видел. Может по cpp-httplib есть  документация, даже на английской сойдёт.

Comment: Хотя я уже нашёл на странице проекта кое какую документацию, классный пример как розшарить папку auto ret = svr.set_mount_point("/", "./www");
if (!ret) {
  // The specified base directory doesn't exist...
}

Comment: какая именно часть кода Вас смущает?

Comment: Не смущает а просто в новинку , что можно часть кода как аргумент передавать, у меня непонимание было скорее из за того что я не видел в конце круглою скобку }); и у меня возникал вопрос, каким это образом  метод svr.Get, знает что нудно включить как я думал независимые фигурные скобки после, ко пока писал комент который стер увидел что фигурные скобки передаються как аргумент и не являються независимыми.

Comment: это называется лямбда. этому синтаксису уже более 10 лет. Если в Ваших учебниках по с++ этого нет, то выбросьте их, они не учат с++.

Comment: Изучать я начал лет 8 назад но изучали на сколько понимаю стандарт 2003 года. Но я уже понял что неплохо пройтись по основам еще раз. Только по новым стандартам.

Comment: ищите книгу Страуструпа о с++ 11/14 (обложка с птицами). Но только внимательно, так как есть такая же, но старая. читайте.

Comment: Благодарю, буду искать.