# Полноценный https Сервер на с++ (библиотека)

Tags: c++, c, http, веб-сервер, https

Подскажите пожалуйста, кто нибудь знает кроссплатформенную быструю библиотеку на С или С++ реализующую https 1.1(или 2.0) сервер ?

Под быстрой библиотекой я подразумеваю, что она будет использовать на Windows - IO completion ports, а на Linux - epoll.

Скорее всего я "губу раскатал" - но может быть кто знает, может быть сие чудо существует ?

Comment: [Apache](https://github.com/apache/httpd)

Comment: @AlexGlebe, апач не использует ни epoll, ни порты завершения к сожалению.

Comment: Может быть для начала вы опишите проблему, а не, как вам кажется, способ её решения?

Comment: Вот такое пробовали https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1375025/2739 ?

Comment: @ArchDemon, но, как таковой проблемы нет. А чем не устроил вопрос ? Или такие вопросы задавать нельзя ?

Comment: Потому что в текущем виде ваш вопрос похож на https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/Что-такое-Ошибка-молотка-или-Ошибка-xy

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html - пожалуйста